# Chasan cigarettes - source & reason

Tags: minhag, tobacco-cig-smoking, chassan-groom

Years ago it was a popular custom that a Chasan would give out cigarettes to his friends. Nowadays some still do so, however as smoking has become less popular so has this Minhag. What is the source and reason that a Chasan gives out cigarettes?

Comment: Chasan Domeh LeMelekh and a king has a right to kill people at will.

Comment: @DoubleAA im feeling ptij q here

Comment: The reason I heard back in my Chassan days was that so the recipient should find a light and thus tell another person the news. In other words, it was a way of spreading word of the engagement.

Comment: @Mefaresh, if you feel like a ptij, there is [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3691/why-didnt-avraham-tell-eliezer-to-go-get-rivka#comment4097_3691)

Comment: Cause the Kalla always only agreed to marry them if they quit, so they gave them all away.

Comment: I haven't seen this done in a LONG time. It was common in U.S., at least, to give cigars to people when your son / daughter was born. I vaguely recall, the father distributing cigars at his son's Bar Mitzvah. It seems it was just a custom to "relax and celebrate" good news with a stogie, similar to the notion that Jews now celebrate good news with a schnapps. According to Jackie Mason, though, these days, Goyim celebrate with a drink; Jews celebrate with cake!

Comment: I just heard Hakham 'Ovadiah Yosef A"H reference this minhag in his Motza'ei Shabbat shi'ur on Parashat Behar (התשע"א) as regards smoking on Yom Tov ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SuIUrMFHB-I&feature=youtu.be&t=1386)).

Comment: Good timing for this question, as IY"H I'm attending a wedding of my friend's son. I knew him when he was born and fed him a bottle a few times. (Actually, what was IN the bottle.) If the chattan gives me a cigarette, I might be offended. This is how he thanks me for feeding him???

Comment: When I first saw this custom I asked why. I was told, "So you should find your own match."

Comment: I gave cigars! I dont think everything that is done is a 'Jewish' minhag.

Comment: I think that this should be re-asked as PTIJ next Adar ב

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Natai Gavriel ([Shidduchim V'Tanaim 23:17](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46551&st=&pgnum=282)) says this is not a good custom - and recommends giving out delicacies instead - but in the footnote notes that מנהגי לעלוב does bring this custom as a way of avoiding Eiyen Hara - in other words, of reducing any jealous reaction among those who hear the news.

Comment: The link in your post is to this question. Cut and paste error?

Comment: @Bachrach44 Fixed link

Comment: @Bachrach44 Amazing that this post got 5 upvotes and an accept with such an error in it. Why isn't anyone checking sources???

Comment: In my yeshiva, the custom is to bring a bag of assorted candies during breakfast.